# Cannot Logout from IdentityServer 4 through Azure SAML logout request

Tags: azure, identityserver4, saml, sustainsys-saml2

**Context**

I have a Service Provider (SP) based on IdentityServer 4 and Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2 that is configured to use Azure as an IdP (SAML2).
I also have a SPA with an api that connects to my SP (with oidp) to identify my user. The api then creates a JWT for my user to use.

I can login my user correctly.

**Question**

My issue comes with the logout. I want to use the logout url parameter of Azure to notify my SP about the logout. I manage to see the SAML Logout Request as a string when I configure an endpoint of mine but I can't exploit it and parsing it manually does't seem right.

Is there an existing endpoint that would come with my dependencies that I missed?
The goal here is to revoke all my user's application sessions (the apps to which my user is connected throug my SP).

**Configuration**

Idp configuration in the SP (called in Startup.cs).
The Saml2AuthModel comes from a config file.

```
 public static AuthenticationBuilder AddSaml2Auth(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Saml2AuthModel saml2AuthModel)
  {
     builder.AddSaml2(saml2AuthModel.Scheme, saml2AuthModel.DisplayName ?? saml2AuthModel.Scheme, options =>
     {
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
        options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

        options.SPOptions.EntityId = new EntityId(saml2AuthModel.ServiceProviderEntityId);

        options.SPOptions.ModulePath = "/" + saml2AuthModel.ModulePath ?? saml2AuthModel.Scheme ?? options.SPOptions.ModulePath;

        var idp = new IdentityProvider(
           new EntityId(saml2AuthModel.IdentityProviderEntityId),
           options.SPOptions
        );

        idp.MetadataLocation = saml2AuthModel.IdentityProviderMetadataLocation;

        options.IdentityProviders.Add(idp);
     });

     return builder;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sustainsys.Saml2 library has support for single logout. To enable it, you need to set up a service signing key. The reason is that logout requests and responses should be signed. So the library doesn't expose the logout endpoints if it has no signing keys available.